# Code not executing within nested async methods

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await

I'm stuck on why I am not able to get a value returned from an async method call.

I do not receive any errors.

The **ReadAsync** method does not fully execute leaving me unable to step through remaining lines of code.

Please help.
You are my only hope...

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        QuoteParameters quote = e.Parameter as QuoteParameters;
        Debug.Assert(quote != null);

        var task = _viewModel.GenerateQuote(quote);
        string address = task.Result;
        webView.Source = new Uri(address);
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateQuote(QuoteParameters quote)
    {
        var documentedQuote = quote.Convert();
        var task = QuoteGenerator.Execute(documentedQuote);

        string filePath = await task; **// EXECUTION STOPS AT THIS POINT!**

        return filePath;
    }


    public async static Task<string> Execute(QuoteParameters quote)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;

        foreach (var service in quote.Services)
        {
            var quoteTemplateTask = IO.ReadAsync(TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY, DOC_TEMPLATE);
            string quoteTemplate = await quoteTemplateTask;

            var serviceTemplateTask = IO.ReadAsync(TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY, SERVICE_TEMPLATE);
            string serviceTemplate = await serviceTemplateTask;

            var serviceAppliedTemplate = Apply(quoteTemplate, quote.Services, serviceTemplate);

            var materialTemplate = IO.ReadAsync(TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY, MATERIAL_TEMPLATE);
            html = Apply(serviceAppliedTemplate, service.Materials, await materialTemplate);
        }

        return await SaveAsync(html);
    }

    public static async Task<string> ReadAsync(string directoryExtension, string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = BuildPath(directoryExtension, fileName);
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

        StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directoryName);
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName); **// EXECUTION STOPS HERE**

        IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        IInputStream inputstream = randomAccessStream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputstream);

        var numberOfBytesLoaded = dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)randomAccessStream.Size);

        return dataReader.ReadString(await numberOfBytesLoaded);
    }
```

Comment: How do you know that "ReadAsync does not fully execute" when execution stops in method GenerateQuote? If we're "your only hope" wouldn't it be better to provide more info? And, more to the point, why don't you ever accept answers? Be courteous and reciprocate the knowledge others are sharing with you. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: does changing the code to `string quoteTemplate = await IO.ReadAsync(TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY, DOC_TEMPLATE);` make a difference?

Comment: Does a completion work, e.g. `storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName).Completed = () => { // Lambda expression to handle result }`? You often need to do this with WinRT development to avoid RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD issues.

Comment: How do you call `GenerateQuote()`? Don't you use `Wait()` there by any chance?

Comment: spender - I usually find a different way of implementing whatever behavior, give up, or I find a solution on another thread.

Comment: Peter - I tried both and receive the same issue.

Comment: Akton - I attempted to try your suggestion. I guess I need help understanding why I'm experiencing execution calls being suspended and never resuming. With your suggestion, I do not know how to resolve a compile error on the return statement. I know why the compiler is complaining. I'm just do not understand why this is so complicated for me.

Comment: Svick - I updated the code example with the xaml-code-behind call.

Comment: I didn't decorate my xaml call-back file with async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `OnNavigatedTo`. Specifically, your call to `Task.Result` is causing a deadlock. [Don't block on `async` code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

You could try this, but I'm not sure how well `OnNavigatedTo` will work being `async` (the method will return before setting `webView.Source`, which may not be what you want):

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    QuoteParameters quote = e.Parameter as QuoteParameters;
    Debug.Assert(quote != null);

    var task = _viewModel.GenerateQuote(quote);
    string address = await task;
    webView.Source = new Uri(address);
}
```